# Is setting up a CA server necessary when all I want is to test HTTPS for a web project on localhost?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

[This freeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/development-production-parity-with-valid-https-certs/) recommends

- setting up a **CA server**,
- installing the **CA root certificate** file into the system's trust store, and
- generating a **leaf certificate** for the project's web server.

Based on my understanding of the [TLS handshake](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/) for HTTPS, setting up a **CA server** seems to be an overkill because:

- A **CA server** is basically a complex software taking care of certificate operations (e.g., issue, revoke, keep track) and organizational tasks (policies, RAs, etc.), but at the core are the identities of the CAs in the hierarchy (i.e., the certificates and the key-pairs of root and intermediate CAs), which are simply bits stored in files.
- The [CA servers are never contacted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188266/how-are-ssl-certificates-verified) during the TLS handshake (neither by the browser or the server), because [the browsers and operating systems have their own copy of CA public keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102681/where-does-the-list-of-trusted-content-authorities-come-from-when-using-a-web-br) to verify the certificates' signatures. Thus, when my fictitious CA certificate is added to the list, then the work is done.

---

[The freeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/development-production-parity-with-valid-https-certs/) uses the [`step-ca`](https://github.com/smallstep/certificates) and [`step-cli`](https://github.com/smallstep/cli) tools, where the former is a full-fledged CA server and the latter can be used as an interface to it, but [it can also be used "offline"](https://smallstep.com/docs/step-ca/certificate-authority-core-concepts/#offline-mode) for [generic cryptographic tasks](https://smallstep.com/docs/step-cli/basic-crypto-operations/).

Specifically, the [(smallstep) Create and work with X.509 certificates](https://smallstep.com/docs/step-cli/basic-crypto-operations/#create-a-certificate-authority) section in the documentation seems to confirm my thoughts above by providing manual steps on how to create root & intermediate CA and a leaf certificate, all of which can be used right away.

---

A [blog post with detailed steps](https://imagineer.in/blog/https-on-localhost-with-nginx/) to achieve the same thing as in the [smallstep](https://smallstep.com/docs/step-cli/basic-crypto-operations/#create-a-certificate-authority) docs, but with more explanation and on a lower level (e.g., it uses `openssl` and system tools to install the root cert).

Comment: For using HTTPS with localhost you can use a simple self-signed certificate (i.e. a certificate signed by itself), which you then explicitly trust in your client.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use mkcert, which is a tool that automates this process of creating a locally trusted TLS cert for development, by former Golang security lead and current Go standard library TLS stack maintainer.

https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert